# Is there a queue manager for CruiseControl.NET?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

Let's say I have three projects:

```
  <project name="Foo" queue="Q1" queuePriority="1">...</project>

  <project name="Bar" queue="Q1" queuePriority="1">...</project>

  <project name="Lambda" queue="Q1" queuePriority="1">...</project>
```

and 'Lambda' is currently building. Two co-workers click Force build on both 'Foo' and 'Bar'. Both are added to the queue. Let's say 'Bar' is added first, then 'Foo'.

Is there a queue manager for CCnet to *reorder* the 'Q1' queue from the dashboard (or from a tray app)?

If not, is it theoretically possible to write a plugin for this functionality?

Comment: I wonder why you want to do this? Maybe your problem can be solved in a another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there exists no such application and it would require profound changes to the CC.net server in order to do it.

You can remove a forced build from the queue by stopping the project. (Remember then to restart it.) and you can control how forced buils are queued to some extent by configuring the `duplicates` attribute of a CC.net queue, for example "ApplyForceBuildsReAddTop"` will queue forced buils before regular ones. However even this does not allow you to control the order of *forced builds*.